# как в реакт реализовать изменение стилей элемента при наведении?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

делаю небольшое spa на реакте и возник вопрос, как реализовать подобный функционал?

```
/*код примерно такой*/
function Menu() {
return (
  <div className='menu'>
    <div className='btns'>
      <button/><button/><button/><button/>
    </div>
    <div className='acc-section'>
      <div className='acc-img'/>
      <button/>
    </div>
  </div>
)
}
```

понимаю,что надо это как то через состояние элемента сделать и менять его через onMouseEnter, но как через состояние сообщать стили? Не делать же это через условные рендеринг по типу `if (stateName == ...) {return 'hidden'/*класс*/}`

Comment: А почему нельзя просто через св-во CSS `hover`?

Comment: @Mr.Man хм... и действительно, можно=/ Но, все же, если стояла бы задача именно через реакт такое сделать, нужно было бы через состояние этим заниматься?